# ретрансляция аудио на PHP

Tags: php, аудио

мне нужно что бы php-скрипт на сервере принимал аудио поток(например от shoutcast-сервера), и раздавал его клиентам.
То есть, у меня дома будет работать сервер радио. Но канал на отправку у меня узкий.
И я хочу использовать хостинг с PHP для раздачи моего потока.
Подскажите, как это правильно называется, что бы я понял, как искать в гугле, или, если не сложно, то покажите, что почитать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путем использования сервиса [Listen To My Radio](http://listen2myradio.com)